# What is the point in using Monte Carlo simulation to compute π?

Tags: pi, monte-carlo

I recently read about computing π using a Monte Carlo simulation in a MIT Course, and I thought that π is in no way related to randomness, absolutely it is related to the Pythagorean Theorem, for sure.

Instead of generate random points (as these random points are equally probable in a frequency bin) you could just compute a grid, and see if the point is inside the circle, if you need more precision you can increase the grid resolution.

What's the point of using Monte Carlo to compute π? It's a kind of joke? Interesting fact? Or it is just an illustration?

Comment: Without more context, its hard to say. However, I think its just a way of helping you understand the types of things monte carlo simulation can do. It probably isn't super practical to do this (there are better ways to calculate pi anyway) but its meant to be another example to help a student understand.

Comment: In fact , such methods are not practical at all, but in theory, they could calculate $\pi$. From a theoretical point of view, it is interesting that the needle problem is related to $\pi$ or even the probability that two random positive integers are coprime.

Comment: For $\pi$ there is no point besides pedagogy. But if you consider an analogous problem of finding the hyper-volume of some very high dimensional shape by "throwing darts" in the same way, Monte Carlo becomes a more viable option.